# Bitmap moving is not smooth

Tags: actionscript-3

I've a Bitmap object lagging problem.

it doesn't move smoothly when I used onEnterFrame or TweenMax to move it.

**onEnterFrame Test**

http://wonderfl.net/c/j2x6

**tweenMax Test**

http://wonderfl.net/c/reqA

How can I move it  smoothly like this case?

www.monoslideshow.com/demo

in **transition properties>Ken Burns mode, time and strength>choice auto pan>press refresh**

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flash it can move each 0.1 pixels. Because it is on the flash stage. But visible is like each 0.2-0.5 pixels movement.

The reason why you can not see it moving smooth, because the animation speed is to slow...
If you want to make a smooth bitmap movement. you need:

Increase the FPS or/and Increase the Speed of animation.

Comment: Hi Jevgenij,thans your reply^^

Answer (score 1):

You CAN do something to get smooth animation:

with this trick you can fix it:

```
img.scaleX = img.scaleY = 1.01;
img.smoothing = true
```